# Office365 / MS Outlook email address variations

Tags: office365

Does anyone know if you can use different variations of email address from microsoft?

For example with gmail I can send email to:

`something@gmail.com` and `something+123456@gmail.com`

And it will arrive to the same mailbox.

I just tried that with my MS email and it didn't arrive.
Is it possible to enable it, or are there other variations I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, only for Outlook.com. Office 365 doesn't support this, you'll need to add proxy address for each of the "plus-email".

Comment: Yeah another hour of googling did the same result.. big letdown as I need dynamic aliases